# Draw samples from KDE based on empirical data (to calculate entropy)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density, probability-density

I am trying to calculate the entropy (`scipy.stats.entropy`) between two arrays of numerical values, to quantify the difference of their underlying distributions.

As calculating the entropy requires both inputs to have the same shape, I want to estimate the distribution of the smaller list using KDE to sample new data from it.

Working with inputs between 0 and 1e-02 I am not able to draw plausible numbers from the fitted KDE?

```
emp_values = np.array([0.000618, 0.000425, 0.000597, 0.000528, 0.000393, 0.000721,
   0.000674, 0.000703, 0.000632, 0.000383, 0.000466, 0.000919,
   0.001419, 0.00063 , 0.000433, 0.000516, 0.001419, 0.000655,
   0.000674, 0.000676, 0.000694, 0.000396, 0.000688, 0.00061 ,
   0.000687, 0.000633, 0.000601, 0.00061 , 0.000747, 0.000356,
   0.000824, 0.000931, 0.000691, 0.000907, 0.000553, 0.000748,
   0.000828, 0.000907, 0.000457, 0.000494])
kde_emp = KernelDensity().fit(emp_values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Using `KDE.sample` to draw random numbers yields values completely out of range?

```
kde_emp.sample(10)
array([[-3.0811253 ],
   [ 1.24822136],
   [ 0.07815318],
   [ 0.01609681],
   [-0.59676707],
   [-0.89988083],
   [-0.59071966],
   [-0.72741754],
   [ 0.82296101],
   [ 0.08329316]])
```

What would be then the appropriate way to draw 10.000 random samples from the fitted PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `bandwidth` of the KDE defaults to 1, which is far too large.  try using something like this instead:

```
kde_emp = KernelDensity(bandwidth=5e-5)
kde_emp.fit(emp_values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

to set the bandwidth to something more sensible for this data.  the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) talks about what bandwidth means

I don't know scikit-learn very well, but [there doesn't seem to be](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10467) any nice way of estimating this value automatically in it.  i.e. you'd have to write your own estimator (~5 to 10 lines of code) yourself

that said, if you're just after a Gaussian KDE then SciPy has one that does estimate the bandwidth for you.  see [`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html).   note that the scipy estimator assumes the data is unimodal (as most do) whereas your data certainly isn't, so you'd need a smaller bandwidth value

Comment: using a bandwidth of e.g. 1e-6 really helped, and produced the desired outcome. Thanks!

Comment: it occurred to me that you could probably just sample (with replacement) from the values.  note that you're probably better off using a measure that can handle different data sizes.  any resizing like this will tend screw up estimates of variance